# Error running aurelia-cli app

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I've been trying to start a new Aurelia project using the CLI. Unfortunately I've been unable to get it running, as detailed below.

Steps to reproduce:

1. au new
2. Give name & choose Typescript
3. cd into directory
4. au run

Results in the following output/error

```
$ au run
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'copyFiles'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'copyFiles'
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildTypeScript'...
Finished 'buildTypeScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
Tracing app...
Tracing environment...
Tracing main...
Tracing resources/index...
Tracing app...
Tracing aurelia-binding...
Tracing aurelia-bootstrapper...
Tracing aurelia-dependency-injection...
Tracing aurelia-event-aggregator...
Tracing aurelia-framework...
Tracing aurelia-history...
Tracing aurelia-history-browser...
Tracing aurelia-loader-default...
Tracing aurelia-logging-console...
Tracing aurelia-pal-browser...
Tracing aurelia-route-recognizer...
Tracing aurelia-router...
Tracing aurelia-templating-binding...
Tracing text...
Tracing aurelia-templating-resources...
Tracing aurelia-templating-router...
Tracing aurelia-testing...
{ uid: 10,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: [SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode],
  duration: [ 1, 662379750 ],
  time: 1494208589928 }
{ uid: 1,
  name: '<series>',
  branch: true,
  error: [SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode],
  duration: [ 3, 229638964 ],
  time: 1494208589941 }
{ uid: 0,
  name: '<series>',
  branch: true,
  error: [SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode],
  duration: [ 3, 231269291 ],
  time: 1494208589942 }
[SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode]
```

Environment:

- Windows 10
- NPM version: 4.5.0
- Aurelia CLI version: 0.27.0

Comment: update your NodeJS version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aurelia CLI does not support NodeJS 4.x. You must have at least NodeJS 6.x.

Comment: Cheers, that fixed it :)